# Assigning classes as variables

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

Ok, I'm still a beginner when it comes to object oriented programming, but I'm not sure why my code is completely altering the attributes of the class when assigning a temporary variable equivalent to the class.

```
class L1:
    value = 3
class L2:
    value = 1
class derived:
    value = 3523

def setValue(derived,Input):

    if len(Input) == 0:
        print 'Error, LIST HAS NO ENTRY'
        return 0
    elif len(Input) == 1:
        derived.value = 1
        return derived
    else:
        result = derived
        result.value = 0
        temp = derived
        for i in Input:
            print result.value
            temp.value = i.value
            print temp.value
            result.value = result.value | temp.value
        return result

def main():
    a = L1()
    b = L2()
    c = derived()
    x = [a,b]
    c = setValue(c,x)

main()
```

When I assigned temporary variable result equal to the class derived and changed the value attribute of result, it completely changed derived's value attribute. Now the variable temp also has a value of 0. Is it supposed to do that? How can I make it so that only the result's value attribute is zero, and temp is still set to the derived's value attribute.

In other words, at the end, I want c.value to be 4.

Comment: "assigning a temporary variable equivalent to the class" - that's not creating a new class "equivalent" to the original. Both the new variable and the original refer to the exact same class. Modifications to the class through either variable will be visible to the other. The only operation on `result` that wouldn't show up in `derived` is `result = something_new`, because assignment is an operation on the variable itself, rather than on the object it refers to.

Comment: this is completely not what classes are for.  why are you using classes for this at all?

Comment: The style of this code is difficult, confusing and hard to follow. Keep things simple. It is Python after all. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the issue is in this code:

```
    result = derived
    result.value = 0
    temp = derived
    for i in Input:
        temp.value = i.value
        result.value = result.value + temp.value
    return result
```

Note that `temp`, `result` and `derived` all point to the same object, and you write to that object's `value` a number of times. Fundamentally, your current loop is the same as:

```
    derived.value = 0
    for i in Input:
        derived.value = derived.value + derived.value
    return derived
```

Personally, I don't understand why that function isn't just:

```
def setValue(derived, Input):
    if len(Input) == 0:
        print 'Error, LIST HAS NO ENTRY'
        return None
    elif len(Input) == 1:
        derived.value = 1
        return derived
    else:
        derived.value = sum(x.value for x in Input)
        return derived
```

Or even just:

```
def setValue(derived, Input):
    derived.value = sum(x.value for x in Input)
    return derived
```

And if we wanted to explode this into an actual loop, we would do:

```
def setValue(derived, Input):
    derived.value = 0
    for elem in Input:
        derived.value += elem.value
    return derived
```

If we do this, then we can see that the following main will produce your expected value of **4**.

```
c = setValue(derived(), [L1(), L2()])
print c.value
```

Comment: I would favor `if not Input:` over `if len(Input) == 0:`

Comment: @dano: I'd rather not make small changes to his/her code all over the place. We could also talk about class variables vs instance variables as well.

Comment: The reason why I'm not doing that is that I want to do a bit OR operation with result.value and temp.value. Sorry that I forgot to mention it above, but I don't believe there's a function call for the bit operation or.

Comment: `derived.value = functools.reduce(operator.or_, (x.value for x in Input))`

Comment: Ok, thanks. What module do I import for functools? is it just import functools?

Comment: Yes. [`import functools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) and [`import operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

Comment: Actually I found another way to do it. Thanks for all your help.